# Error Message while installing php5-intl

Tags: php

When I try to install php5-intl, I got this error message. What does mean of this message? Anybody can help me to explain this message? Should I remove php5-common first?  or anything else?

```
root@dremi-ubuntu-X450JF:/var/www/html/cakephp3# sudo apt-get install php5-intl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-intl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@dremi-ubuntu-X450JF:/var/www/html/cakephp3#
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy php5-intl php5-common`

```
    root@dremi-ubuntu-X450JF:/var/www/html/cakephp3# apt-cache policy php5-intl php5-common
php5-intl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
php5-common:
  Installed: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
root@dremi-ubuntu-X450JF:/var/www/html/cakephp3#
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy php5-intl php5-common`.

Comment: Hello muru, here is the outputs: 
http://pastie.org/10117478

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in your APT sources.

You can see that because of the version of your `php5-common` packages which is `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4` whereas you `php5-intl` package version is only `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4`.

Also, your current `php5-common` package version comes from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` indicating it can not be associated to any currently known APT source.

Therefore, it could mean that you used an APT source to install `php5-common` and removed it after then, or that your package lists are not up to date.

I recommend:

- checking your `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- running `apt-get update` (it should be done before installing any package)

Comment: I have checked `/etc/apt/sources.list`, what should I do next? after run `apt-get update`, still not work for `apt-get install php5-intl`

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/php5-common you should get the `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9` version for php5 packages in Trusty, and certainly not `5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4` which is obsolete by 9 versions. If the `apt-get update` command showed no error, I would recommend you to try with another Ubuntu mirror.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to update from another mirror.

Comment: I have done for run apt-get update, after change mirror to http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu. then try again to run apt-get install php5-intl, but there is no changes.

Comment: What is the new result now for `apt-cache policy php5-intl php5-common` ?

Comment: the new result http://pastie.org/10117614

Comment: This new result shows the same problem. But you still used a mirror from the same country (id = Indonesia), and I guess the new one is getting its data from the previous one. Try using a mirror from another country.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23244/discussion-between-progfou-and-muhammad-khairul-azami).

Comment: Hello progfou, let me take some conclussion. So, this is mirror source problem right? After that, I try to search in google to get good source for php5-intl, then I founded this link http://www.brandonlamb.com/posts/install-php55-on-ubuntu-1404-lts, `apt-get install php5-intl` working good now. thank you!

Comment: Just to share, now my php version was changed from `PHP 5.5.9-1 ubuntu4.4` to `PHP Version 5.5.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2`. I have checked it from phpinfo.

Comment: Just a warning: you didn't manage the ground problem here (APT sources not up-to-date), you only get a solution for a specific need (getting php5-intl installed). So you'll probably get further troubles with your next package installs until you finally use up-to-date APT sources.

Comment: So, should i run `apt-get upgrade` too, instead `apt-get update` only?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it may be because you choose to hold some packages, forbidding them to get upgrades.

You can check for hold packages with these commands:

- If you are using aptitude: `aptitude search "~ahold"`
- If you are using apt-get: `dpkg --get-selections | grep 'hold$'`

Comment: hello progfou, i try to run `aptitute search "~ahold"`, the output is `root@dremi-ubuntu-X450JF:/var/www/html/cakephp3# aptitude search "~ahold"
The program 'aptitude' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install aptitude
You have new mail in /var/mail/root`

so, i type apt-get install aptitude. then try to apt-get install php5-intl again, still not work.

Comment: Well, you don't really need aptitude. If you are not using aptitude, just use the second line to check for hold packages. What is the answer from the second one?

Comment: the second  line didn't show anything on console

Comment: So you don't have any hold package. It's more likely an APT source problem, hence my second answer. :-)

Comment: ok, but I don't know about the APT source problem.